# Why does converting Hex 0x00000000 to float give 5.8774717541114E-39 instead of 0.00 in PHP when used with a function?

Tags: php, binary, hex, decimal, floating-point-conversion

I am using a function to convert hexadecimal numbers to floating point numbers. The function does not give me the right value for (0x00000000). I am using the following PHP function.

```
function hex2float($number) {
    $binfinal = sprintf("%032b",hexdec($number));
    $sign = substr($binfinal, 0, 1);
    $exp = substr($binfinal, 1, 8);
    $mantissa = "1".substr($binfinal, 9);
    $mantissa = str_split($mantissa);
    $exp = bindec($exp)-127;
    $significand=0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
        $significand += (1 / pow(2,$i))*$mantissa[$i];
    }
    return $significand * pow(2,$exp) * ($sign*-2+1);
}
```

Here is how I call the function

```
echo hex2float("0x00000000");
```

The output is **5.8774717541114E-39** which is wrong.

How do I get 0.00 from this function?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the problem. Rounding off the return value of the function solved it for me.

```
return round($significand * pow(2,$exp) * ($sign*-2+1), 3);
```